# Database Diff Script without table drops

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2012

I need to move my teams database changes from our development environment to our test environment.

I know that Visual Studio can diff two databases and output a script.  But for tables that we have added columns it is dropping the table and re-inserting in with the new columns.

It tries to keep the data, but it is not going to work.  It will cause FK issues, and when I try to move this to production, I will lose all the statistics on the table.

Is there a way to get it to script the table with an alter script?  (So that it alters the table to add the new column?)

Comment: You could of course manually alter the scripts to be an `alter` script, but I don't know if that's your intent?

Answer (score 0):

I see this happen when columns are added to the middle of a table. If you're doing that, don't.

Comment: Ben, in what way is this an answer to the question? Please provide comments to the question if you have remarks next time, thanks.

Comment: Because this exact behavior happens when the steps that I've outlined occur. So, it stands to reason that if you don't want that behavior to manifest that not adding columns to the middle of the table would be a way to avoid it. And since the poster was looking for a way to avoid having the designer create a drop and create scrip, this seems like an answer to me.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. But when a database already is in test we never drop and create the table anymore. We then only use `ALTER TABLE` scripts. That way columns only will be added to the bottom of the list. That's one way to avoid this.